# Calculations in SQL and preventing Divide By Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to rework a query that is based on cursors.

The query calculates certain stats based on multiple values. In the snippet below the first, second and third `CASE` works out the happiness of `Unit1`.  Any of these fields are 0 (they can never be `NULL`) I will get a `Divide by Zero` error.  I could just add 1 to each field `(Unit2 + 1) / (Unit1 + 1)` and that will stop the error.  However, it seems like a bodge and it will potentially give the incorrect result.  ie. `Unit1` needs the same amount of `Unit2` to keep them happy.  If I have one `Unit1` and no `Unit2` this bodge will give 100% happy for that check.  So my first problem is how do I prevent the divide by zero but not distort the results. Each `CASE` gives me a `%` happy

```
Select 

CASE WHEN ((Unit2 / Unit1) * 100) > 100 Then 100 Else ((Unit2 / Unit1) * 100) END Unit1Happy1,
CASE WHEN ((Stock3 / (Unit1 * 2)) * 100) > 100 Then 100 Else ((Stock3 / (Unit1 * 2)) * 100) END Unit1Happy2,
CASE WHEN (((Drug3 + (Drug1 / 2)) / Unit1) * 100)  > 100 Then 100 Else (((Drug3 + (Drug1 / 2)) / Unit1) * 100)  END Unit1Happy3,
CASE WHEN (((Weapon6 + Weapon7 + Weapon8 + Weapon9) / Unit2) * 100) > 100 Then 100 ELSE (((Weapon6 + Weapon7 + Weapon8 + Weapon9) / Unit2) * 100) END Unit2Happ1,
CASE WHEN (((Stock2 + (Stock1 / 2)) / Unit2) * 100)  > 100 Then 100 Else (((Stock2 + (Stock1 / 2)) / Unit2) * 100) END Unit2Happ2

FROM tblUserFiles
```

My next problem is that I need to take to lowest value for each UnitHappiness and store that value in the table.  So in `tblUserFiles` are 5 fields `Unit1Happ`, `Unit2Happ` .... `Unit5Happ`.  Looking at the above query if `Unit1Happy1` is the lowest figure I store that figure into `Unit1Happ`, If `Unit2Happy` is the lowest I store that etc.

My record Identifier is `UserId` and I need to run this for a given `UserId` or for the whole table.

What I am basically asking is:

- What is the best method to identify the lowest value of each Unit
  calculation?
- What is the best way to prevent the divide by zero
  error?
- Can I approach this problem in a better way?

**Update**

I am working through the suggestions posted in the answers below.  As this is just a training exercise it may take a while. I do have a working query that gives the results I am looking for I am just not sure if the suggested answers would be more efficient.

```
Update tblUserFiles Set Unit1Happ = happyvals.Unit1Happiness, Unit2Happ = happyvals.Unit2Happiness, Unit3Happ = happyvals.Unit3Happiness, Unit4Happ = happyvals.Unit4Happiness, Unit5Happ = happyvals.Unit5Happiness FROM

(SELECT ch.UserId,
Case When ch.Unit1Happy1 < ch.Unit1Happy2 And ch.Unit1Happy1 < ch.Unit1Happy3 Then ch.Unit1Happy1
            When ch.Unit1Happy2 < ch.Unit1Happy1 And ch.Unit1Happy2 < ch.Unit1Happy3 Then ch.Unit1Happy2 
            Else ch.Unit1Happy3
End As Unit1Happiness,
CASE WHEN ch.Unit2Happy1 > ch.Unit2Happy2 THEN ch.Unit2Happy1
            ELSE ch.Unit2Happy2
END AS Unit2Happiness, 
ch.Unit3Happy1 AS Unit3Happiness,
ch.Unit4Happy1 AS Unit4Happiness,
ch.Unit5Happy1 AS Unit5Happiness
FROM
(

Select 
UserId,
CASE    WHEN Unit2 = 0 OR Unit1 = 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN ((Unit2 / Unit1) * 100) > 100 Then 100 
        ELSE ((Unit2 / Unit1) * 100) 
END Unit1Happy1,
CASE    WHEN Stock3 = 0 OR Unit1 = 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN ((Stock3 / (Unit1 * 2)) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 
        ELSE ((Stock3 / (Unit1 * 2)) * 100) 
END Unit1Happy2,
CASE    WHEN Unit1 = 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN Drug3 = 0 AND Drug1 = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN Drug1 = 0 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN (Drug3 / Unit1) * 100 > 100 THEN 100
                            ELSE (Drug3 / Unit1) * 100
                        END
        WHEN Drug3 = 0 THEN
                        CASE WHEN (Drug1 / 2) / Unit1 > 100 THEN 100
                            ELSE (Drug1 / 2) / Unit1
                        END
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN (((Drug3 + (Drug1 / 2)) / Unit1) * 100) > 100 THEN 100
                ELSE (((Drug3 + (Drug1 / 2)) / Unit1) * 100)
            END

END Unit1Happy3,
CASE    WHEN Unit2 = 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN (Weapon6 + Weapon7 + Weapon8 + Weapon9) = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN (((Weapon6 + Weapon7 + Weapon8 + Weapon9) / Unit2) * 100) > 100 THEN 100
        ELSE (((Weapon6 + Weapon7 + Weapon8 + Weapon9) / Unit2) * 100)
END Unit2Happy1,
CASE    WHEN Unit2 = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN Stock1 = 0 AND Stock2 = 0 THEN 0
        WHEN Stock1 = 0 THEN
            CASE WHEN ((Stock2 / Unit2) * 100)  > 100 THEN 100
                ELSE ((Stock2 / Unit2) * 100)
            END
        WHEN Stock2 = 0 THEN
            CASE WHEN (((Stock1 / 2) / Unit2) * 100)  > 100 THEN 100
                ELSE (((Stock1 / 2) / Unit2) * 100)
            END
        WHEN (((Stock2 + (Stock1 / 2)) / Unit2) * 100)  > 100 THEN 100
        ELSE (((Stock2 + (Stock1 / 2)) / Unit2) * 100)
END Unit2Happy2,    
CASE    WHEN Unit2 = 0 OR Unit3 = 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN ((Unit2 / Unit3) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 
        ELSE ((Unit2 / Unit3) * 100) 
END Unit3Happy1,
CASE    WHEN Unit2 = 0 OR Unit4 = 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN ((Unit2 / Unit4) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 
        ELSE ((Unit2 / Unit4) * 100) 
END Unit4Happy1,
CASE    WHEN Unit2 = 0 OR Unit5 = 0 THEN 0 
        WHEN ((Unit2 / Unit5) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 
        ELSE ((Unit2 / Unit5) * 100) 
END Unit5Happy1
FROM tblUserFiles) ch) happyvals
Join tblUserFiles ON tblUserFiles.UserID = happyvals.UserID
```

Comment: lowest value is best found my `MIN` aggregate function. Or by selecting `TOP 1` and having order by clause. Division by  zero can be avoided with `IF` or with `CASE` statement

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I just stepped away for 2 mins and realised I can prevent the divide by zero in the case. `MIN` that should do the trick.  I should have stepped away before posting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

put a `nullif(Unit1, 0)` around every divide by group ?

Comment: Actually, it does provide an answer, because replacing a zero divisor with `null` prevents the divide by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

The idea is to wrap your division in a UDF (scalar user defined function)....and use the "Max(v)" trick.

The code below may not be perfect, I've supplying the idea.

Cursors are horrible performers, 99.9% of the time.  Try to solve this without cursors.

```
/* or Create */
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.udfSafeDivision (@num float , @denom float)

RETURNS float

AS

BEGIN
    declare @returnValue float
    select @returnValue = 0

        if(isnull(@denom,0) != 0)
        BEGIN
            select @returnValue = convert(float, convert(float, @num)/convert(float, @denom))
        END
    return @returnValue


END


GO


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end


CREATE TABLE #TableOne
( 
SurrogateKey int IDENTITY(1001, 1), 
Unit1 int , 
Unit2 int , 
Stock1 int , 
Stock2 int , 
Stock3 int ,

Drug1 int , 
Drug3 int , 
Weapon6  int ,  Weapon7  int ,  Weapon8  int ,  Weapon9 int

)

Insert into #TableOne (Unit1, Unit2, Stock1, Stock2 , Stock3 , Drug1, Drug3 , Weapon6 , Weapon7 , Weapon8 , Weapon9)
select 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 0
UNION ALL select 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11


UNION ALL select 5 , 1 ,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 5 , 0 ,  0 , 0 , 5 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 10 , 0 ,  0 , 0 , 0 , 5 , 10 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
UNION ALL select 0 , 1 ,  0 , 0 , 0 , 5 , 10 , 10 , 20 , 30 , 40
UNION ALL select 0 , 50 ,  20 , 10 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0


SELECT 
  (SELECT Max(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (Unit1Happy1), (Unit1Happy2), (Unit1Happy3),  (Unit2Happ1), (Unit2Happ2)) AS value(v)) as [MaxValue]
   ,    '--------' as Sep1
   , derived1.*

FROM
(
Select 

CASE WHEN ((dbo.udfSafeDivision(Unit2 , Unit1)) * 100) > 100 Then 100 Else (dbo.udfSafeDivision(Unit2 , Unit1) * 100) END Unit1Happy1,
CASE WHEN (dbo.udfSafeDivision(Stock3 , (Unit1 * 2)) * 100) > 100 Then 100 Else (dbo.udfSafeDivision(Stock3 , (Unit1 * 2)) * 100) END Unit1Happy2,
CASE WHEN (dbo.udfSafeDivision((Drug3 + (Drug1 / 2)) , Unit1) * 100)  > 100 Then 100 Else (dbo.udfSafeDivision((Drug3 + (Drug1 / 2)) , Unit1) * 100)  END Unit1Happy3,
CASE WHEN (dbo.udfSafeDivision((Weapon6 + Weapon7 + Weapon8 + Weapon9) , Unit2) * 100) > 100 Then 100 ELSE (dbo.udfSafeDivision((Weapon6 + Weapon7 + Weapon8 + Weapon9) , Unit2) * 100) END Unit2Happ1,
CASE WHEN (dbo.udfSafeDivision((Stock2 + (Stock1 / 2)) , Unit2) * 100)  > 100 Then 100 Else (dbo.udfSafeDivision((Stock2 + (Stock1 / 2)) , Unit2) * 100) END Unit2Happ2
/* the below is to debug */
, '--' as Sep1
, Unit1, Unit2, Stock1, Stock2 , Stock3 , Drug1, Drug3 , Weapon6 , Weapon7 , Weapon8 , Weapon9
, dbo.udfSafeDivision(Unit2 , Unit1) as Div1
, dbo.udfSafeDivision(Stock3 , (Unit1 * 2)) as Div3

FROM #TableOne
) as derived1



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableOne') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TableOne
end
```

Comment: A few edits made.  You'll have to test your own values.  But I have a few rows return non zero values.